# Как правильно: "не трать время на меня" или "не трать времени на меня"?

Tags: грамотная-речь, управление

Как правильно сказать? Или верны оба варианта?

Answer (score 1):

Вообще-то, глагол с отрицательной частицей НЕ обычно управляет существительным в родительном падеже, особенно, когда это существительное обозначает *абстрактное понятие*:
*не имеет права, не вызывает сомнений, не трать времени*.

Comment: "Не иметь" всегда требует родительного, это отдельный случай, оговорено особо. А вот насчет отнесения **времени** к "абстрактному понятию" я сильно сомневаюсь. Я написал в своем ответе по этому поводу кое-что...

Answer (score 0):

Лучше сказать: не трать на меня время (разг.).

В принципе возможны оба варианта, но стилистически они различны.

При отрицании нейтральным считается Р.п., который характерен  для книжной речи, а также подчеркивает разделительно-количественное значение:  "Я все знаю, не трать времени и сил на меня, они так нужны, так нужны тебе в твоих чудовищных условиях" (Б. Л. Пастернак).

Для  передачи разговорной речи допускается В.п., например: «Не трать время на долгие поиски… Завтра утром, когда будешь бриться, взгляни в зеркало» (Евгений Евтушенко). «Но если хочешь мой совет: не трать время и на проверку» (Василий Шукшин).

Answer (score 0):

Мне больше нравится именно первый вариант: он благозвучнее второго.

Comment: На вкус и цвет товарища нет.

Comment: Но во фразе "У меня нет времени" со словом нет я употребляю родительный падеж. Другое употребление, на мой взгляд, ошибочно.

Answer (score 0):

При переходных  глаголах с отрицательной частицей НЕ употребляется родительный падеж. А посему: не теряйте времЕНи. Используйте справочник Розенталя Д.Э.

Comment: Не всегда родительный. Розенталь пишет: "При переходных глаголах с отрицанием в одних случаях явно преобладает употребление родительного падежа дополнения, в других – употребление винительного падежа, в третьих – наблюдается факультативное их использование". В сочетании "не терять времени" Грамота рекомендует родительный падеж. В отношении "не тратить времени" прямых указаний нет.  Подробно см. на Грамоте:  http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/letters/67-otr

Answer (score 0):

Здесь нет однозначной рекомендации. В современном языке оба варианта возможны.

Вопрос только в том, какой предпочесть.

Грамота позволяет оба варианта "в остальных случаях" - к которым относится и наш, не подпадающий ни под один из там перечисленных.

> В остальных случаях существительные в описываемых конструкциях обычно
>   можно использовать в форме и родительного падежа, и винительного
>   падежа.

http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/letters/67-otr

Вот что лично я думаю на эту тему.

Обычно в таких случаях выбор предопределяет дополнительная мотивация,
в частности по границе конкретный объект - абстрактный.

> При наличии в предложении местоимений, указывающих на определенность
>   объекта: Эту песню не задушишь, не убьешь; он не решил эту задачу
>   (ср.: он не решал задач); Ростов, не желая навязывать свое знакомство,
>   не пошел в дом (Л. Толст.).

Там же.

Но "время" понятие одновременно и конкретное, и абстрактное изначально, у него нет четкого показателя конкретности. "ЭТО время" в данном значении невозможно противопоставить неким "другим временам". Поэтому противопоставление конкретное-абстрактное время тут невозможно. В таких случаях, похоже, возобладает представление о конкретности объекта.

Поэтому я склоняюсь к варианту ***"Не трать время на меня".***

Сравните: "не сберег любовь" (против "не сберег любви"), "не сдержал эмоции", "не принес настроения", "не преодолел расстояние" - все эти варианты выглядят предпочтительнее парных им с родительным.

Кстати наличие уточнения "на меня" тоже способствует выбору варианта с винительным.